# Can't access member of Child Services in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I create 2 services

```
export class BaseService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

And another service like

```
export class ChildService extends BaseService {

  constructor() { 
    super();
  }

  sayHello() { 
     alert("Hello");
  }

}
```

And i used it in component like

```
constructor(private child : ChildService) {
  this.child.sayHello(); // It will throw error that sayHello not available.
}
```

Comment: did u add the service to module provider list

Comment: check if ``this.child`` is ``undefined`` .

Comment: Please post your entire service classes. Right now I‘d say you forgot the @Injectable annotations and thus, the service can‘t get imported properly.

Comment: I have @injectable

Comment: @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

Comment: What happens if you remove the extension an plainly use ChildService?

Comment: i solved it by just removing { providedIn: 'root' } from @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

Comment: @ChintanKukadiya providedIn was introduced in Angular 6 version. If you using Angular 2, you should define providers in the module

Answer (score 2):

Your service should be Injectable:

```
@Injectable
export class BaseService {
...
```

And should be provided to module if it is still not:

```
@NgModule
...
providers: [BaseService]
```

Comment: you dont need Injectable if the has zero dependence